# Partial-mash vs. Mini mash. Is there a difference?

Tags: partial-mash

I've heard of people doing mini mash and partial mash.  I always thought they were interchangeable terms for the same activity.  But the other day I stumbled across someone who said "this works well for both partial mash and mini mash batches".

Is there a difference between the two, or are they synonymous?

Comment: I've always understood them to be synonyms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that a mini-mash is the process of using a small amount of 2-row to alter the fermentability of extract. While a partial mash is simply using a mash for a percentage of your OG.

But when I searched the net before answering this question, it seems that I was wrong -- 'mini-mash' and 'partial-mash' are used interchangeably. There may have been a distinction at one point, but not anymore.

Comment: Your first description of a mini-mash sounds like what I would call a cereal mash. This is where you add enough 2 or 6 row barley malt to some starchy cereal mash (rice, corn, un-malted wheat, etc.) to convert the starches to sugars.

Comment: Not exactly. A cereal mash is for unmalted grains that need extra work to gelatinize. The mini-mash I described is a way for extract brewers to make liquid extract more fermentable.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in my book.  Just synonyms to describe the same thing.